# Load Tinymce for new textarea can't resize

Tags: tinymce

I have a form have 1 textarea (tinymce onload)
And one button to add new textarea (same id,class)

and i start tinymce for this and the first textarea couldn't resizeable ?
but if i already had 2 textarea onload with tinymce, both of them are resizeable !

what's wrong , and how to load tinymce to dynamic textarea?

```
function StartTiny()
{
tinyMCE.init({
});
}
StartTiny();

function AddnewTextarea()
{
action to add new textarea here 
StartTiny();
}
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle for this?